# How to resolve this error message 'Unknown keyword 'section:steel1'. The keyword may be misspelled, obsolete, or invalid'

Tags: abaqus

I am currently having an error message 'Unknown keyword 'section:steel1'. The keyword may be misspelled, obsolete, or invalid'

---

### [image]

error message: Unknown keyword 'section:steel8e3'. The keyword may be misspelled, obsolete,
   or invalid'

I have run the model it was successfully completed, but once I edited to inp.file (the coordinate part only I edited) , and I submitted the modified inp.file , I received the error message mentioned above.

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Show the source where you use it?

Comment: * Section: Steel8e3
*Shell Section, elset=Set-1, material=Steel
0.008, 5
** Section: Section-2-SET-T1
*Shell Section, elset=Set-T1, material=Steel
0.003950333, 5
*Shell Section, elset=Set-T2, material=Steel
0.00414534, 5
*Shell Section, elset=Set-T3, material=Steel
0.00390536, 5

-------------------------------------------

error message:
Unknown keyword 'section:steel8e3'. The keyword may be misspelled, obsolete, or invalid'

Comment: I suggest you put that info in the original question formatted as it is in the real file.

Comment: I have edited the original question, thank you for the advice Solar Mike. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

So, why does this definition look like :
[image]

But this one seems to be missing bits :

[image]

Or are these meant to be one definition and has an extra return? see : 
[image]

Comment: Solar Mike.. I found the answer.. It became error, because I mistakenly deleted the star before Section: Steel8e3

it was supposed to be double star, now the problem solved..

Comment: Now the error message is gone, but another error message appeared

'invalid float value'

Comment: check to make sure you have a complete definition for all cases there...

Comment: Ok, I am going to check it now